# Adding domain name to heroku hosting gave me unknown urls in the DNS Target

Tags: url, heroku, dns, point, cname

I am trying to point my heroku url to my domain name

```
$ heroku domains
=== limo-rent-vancouver Heroku Domain
limo-rent-vancouver.herokuapp.com

=== limo-rent-vancouver Custom Domains
Domain Name      DNS Record Type  DNS Target
───────────────  ───────────────  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
www.limorent.ca  CNAME            evening-springs-1jaz70fwn4eivw1ettgqmsfb.herokudns.com
limorent.ca      ALIAS or ANAME   deep-taro-5a3t14qryjbz96eh1f9ks084.herokudns.com
*.limorent.ca    CNAME            behavioural-gorge-epekec9gk8s8byxtqdqhjrmt.herokudns.com
```

In the DNS target there's three different url. I know that it should be this one https://limo-rent-vancouver.herokuapp.com/ to work.

Can someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely normal. Heroku has been changing the DNS targets these past few years.

Each domain now has it's own target, to prevent abuse cases such as removing a subdomain from an app, but not removing the DNS entry.
Then, anyone could create an app and add your own domain to it, spoofing you.

Comment: But the link that they add doesn't link to anything? How can I point it to the domain name?

Comment: It points to the Heroku router. When a request comes in, it will get your domain's hostname, and properly route to your app.